# Does Fast Retransmit and Retransmission Timer work at the same time?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

When Fast Retransmit is implemented, if I received **packet 1**, then I will send an ACK that says I need **packet 2**, and then if I received **packet 3**, I will send a duplicate ACK that says that I need **packet 2** (and not **packet 4**).

But will **packet 2** on the sender side also have a Retransmission Timer assigned to it, that is, will there be a timer that is waiting for an ACK for **packet 2** to arrive, and if it did not arrive it will retransmit it?

I think that the answer is Yes, because what if the duplicate ACK got lost! is this correct or am I missing something?